# Double entry with UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I got a UITableView in my ViewController. And I want to add, after I enter text in my Textfield and click the button, the text to my tableview. But now the text is entered every time twice.

My Code:

```
@IBAction func pressAddPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        let text = self.spielerTextField.text!
        data.append(text)
        tableview.reloadData()
        tableview.endUpdates()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!   
         let text = data[indexPath.row]  
         cell.textLabel?.text = text 
         return cell
}
```

TY

Comment: add a breakpoint to button click function and check it call twice

Answer (score 1):

No need to use endupdates if you are already using reloadData(). Also I checked your code by replacing the textfield text with a simple string and it was working fine. So can you give some more details as issue is not mainly in this part.

Answer (score 0):

This dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
```

Also, remove no need to use endUpdates here

```
tableview.reloadData()
//tableview.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func pressAddPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        let text = self.spielerTextField.text!
        data.append(text)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
         let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as UITableViewCell   
         let text = data[indexPath.row]  
         cell.textLabel?.text = text 
         return cell
}
```

Try this,it's work fine.